# Automapper with DbGeography results in exception: "The WellKnownValue..."

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper. I want to map a property of type DbGeography, like PlayerFromCache.Position to PlayerFromDb.Position, both of type player. I keep on getting an error, so I broke down the code to the most simple version:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DbGeography, DbGeography>();
});

var pos1 = DbGeography.PointFromText($"POINT(11.0 12.0)", DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);
var pos2 = DbGeography.PointFromText($"POINT(22.0 23.0)", DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);

Mapper.Map(pos1, pos2);
```

This results in the exception:

**The WellKnownValue property is intended to support serialization and deserialization and should not be set directly.**

I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

When I ignore WellKnownValue, then the mapping does not work:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DbGeography, DbGeography>()
        .ForMember(x => x.WellKnownValue, opt => opt.Ignore()); ;
});
```

After the mapping pos2 is still 22 / 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `DbGeography` is an immutable type, there is no need to create copies of it. Your reduced code to map into an existing instance of `DbGeography` won't work, but that's not supposed to work, and not your ultimate goal anyway, so you can forget about that.

Removing `cfg.CreateMap<DbGeography, DbGeography>();` should cause properties of type `DbGeography` to be assigned directly, without cloning.

Comment: Please see my comment below Lucian's answer.

Comment: @Tillito I've verified in a minimal standalone program that AutoMapper behaves the way I described, and I can't tell how the comment + answer you posted is relevant to the question you asked. Are you sure you didn't end up posting an answer to a different question than the one you asked here?

Comment: Yes, you are right: it turned out that the problem was not as simple. It also envolved Entity Framework. Do you think I should delete the question? On the other hand, my answer can help others who try to cache objects with dbgeography fields and use EF and Automapper like I do ...

Comment: @Tillito Right now it won't help: the problem it solves isn't described anywhere (not in this question), so people searching for it won't find it. You can describe the problem your answer solves as a new question, tag it appropriately, and self-answer it. As long as the question is good quality, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Ok. I think your answer is the correct answer then. I can not delete the question, so I will just leave it as answered. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

AM works by setting properties and DbGeography doesn't have properties that can be set. So unless you want to use AM for other reasons, it seems easier to do the mapping yourself.

Comment: I tried this. The mapping does not work then any more. I added this to my question.

Comment: Updated. There is nothing to set.

Comment: The problem then was, that Position was always marked as a changed property for the entity framework which resulted in a huge performance decrease because in the real world the position only rarely change. I guess, I simplified my example code too much, in the end.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out that I had simplified my problem too much: as I commented below, after the mapping of the properties I want to save the player to the database, but only in case that changes were made. Unfortunately without any configuration on Automapper, Entity Framework would always assume the Position had changed, which results in many unnessessary updates to the database.

Finally, I solved the problem myself. I hope this can help others here.

My simplified code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Players held in cached and stored in database using Entity Framework
/// </summary>
public class SimplePlayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Position { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string SerializedPosition
    {
        get { return Position.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText; }
        set
        {
            //-- This is crucial for the redundant updates in EF:
            if (value != Position.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText)
            {
                Position = DbGeography.FromText(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get a player from the cache and only save
/// it to the database if any property has changed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int UpdatePlayer(DbContext context)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<SimplePlayer, SimplePlayer>().ForMember(m => m.Position, opt => opt.Ignore());
    });

    //-- Get the player from the cache
    var player = Game.Players.First();

    //-- When you un-comment this line, the result will be 1 
    //-- and the position will be changed in the database
    // player.Position = GeographyHelper.CreatePoint(11, 11);

    //-- Get the same player from the database
    var playerFromDb = context.Set<Player>().Find(player.ID);

    //-- Map the properties
    Mapper.Map(player, playerFromDb);

    //-- Save changes to the database if there are any
    int countChanges = context.SaveChanges();

    return countChanges;
}
```

So, for me it was crucial that UpdatePlayer would only result in 1 if any property had changed.

Sorry for putting the question too simple and thank you for your help.